# How to choose specific data supplier in JUnit?

Tags: java, junit

I have two data suppliers and bunch of tests.

```
@Parameters(name = "good")
public static Collection goodNumbers() {...}

@Parameters(name = "bad")
public static Collection badNumbers() {...}
```

How can I choose a `good` data for one group of tests and a `bad` data for another group?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're using JUnit's `@Parameterized` runner. This runner doesn't support multiple data suppliers. You need a separate test class for each group of tests. The name is only used for naming the data set. Please have a look at the [Parameterized documentation](http://junit.org/javadoc/latest/org/junit/runners/Parameterized.html).